# Will launcher dry the battery quickly?

Tags: applications, battery, battery-life, launcher

I like to **install** `doldol launcher` will it dry battery quickly? or maintain battery backup normal like default `launcher`?

Comment: Compared to the screen no, unless the launcher is madly bloated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be subjective opinions, however, the battery life will depend on what launcher you use. For instance, if the launcher makes heavy usage of internet for fetching data for its widgets, etc., it will surely end up in poor battery life. But again, it will vary from launcher to launcher and what settings you enable/disable in the launcher. I have been using Nova Launcher for a long time, and having no trouble with the battery life.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using many launchers since past 2-years, i have more battery life as compared to my stock launcher.
I believe it all depends on the usage, widgets which you are using on your launcher.
My personal opinion just give a shot to Dodol launcher and try to avoid using widgets which are less required.